# Linux с самых основ (компиляция, установка ядра и тд)

Tags: linux, компиляция, установка, ядро

Всю жизнь пользовался Windows, и что-то внезапно захотелось немного познакомиться с Linux. Хочется разобраться со всем этим делом с самых-самых основ, но чувствую что не хватает некоторого понимания и теоретических познаний и представлений. Есть ряд вопросов, ответы на которые, как мне кажется, могут немного заполнить пробелы в моем понимании того, что такое Linux и с чем его едят. Итак:

- Правильно ли я понимаю, что есть одно единственное и неповторимое ядро Linux, на базе которого разработаны все эти многочисленные дистрибутивы (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint и т.д), и при этом можно установить именно это самое чистое ядро, а не какой-то из дистрибутивов?
- Правильно ли я понимаю, что само по себе ядро это уже по сути ОС, только без графического интерфейса (что-то вроде DOS) а сам GUI-интерфейс можно уже установить отдельно?
- Слышал много раз о том, что ядро в начале обычно нужно скомпилировать, а затем установить. Есть ли возможность получить уже скомпилированное ядро, распространяется ли оно в таком виде? Хорошая ли идея - пытаться скомпилировать это самое ядро Linux на Windows, и насколько это вообще возможно?
- Слышал много раз о всяких менеджерах пакетов, при помощи которых осуществляется установка различного софта в системах на базе Linux, при этом у каждой такой ОС (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint и т.д) свои собственные менеджеры пакетов. А как быть с чистым ядром? Каким образом на него что-то ставится? Каким вообще образом распространяется софт для Linux? Только в open source, с последующей компиляцией? А такие штуки как установочные файлы, .exe-шники и прочее - обычно не используется?
- Если есть только один ПК без установленной ОС, как обычно на него устанавливается ядро Linux?

Пока-что на этом все. За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Сам в Linux не эксперт, но для начала советую поставить Lubuntu. Дистрибутив легковесный, ставится в два клика. Попробуйте  для начала просто «поиграться» с системой, подстроить все под себя (ведь Linux этим и прельщает!). Ознакомьтесь с Unix-философией, научитесь выходить из Vim, поставьте и настройте Conky. Думаю, вы уже поняли, что настройка Linux — вечный кайф :)

Comment: Не стоит изучать линукс с его ядра, вы скорее всего не изучали виндовз с ядра... Для начала поставьте в виртуалку такой дистрибутив, которым владеет ваш ближайший линукс-«гуру». И начинайте изучать линукс, используя такую штуку как bash - это более приблизит вас к самой ОС, чем использование GUI. Найдите на просторах инторнета какую-нибудь книжку по линуксу для начинающих и вперед. А ядром займетесь когда-нибудь в следующий раз.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что есть одно единственное и неповторимое ядро Linux, на базе которого разработаны все эти многочисленные дистрибутивы (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint и т. д).

Не совсем. Едина только база (изначальный исходный код). То есть разработчики дистрибутивов скачивают [исходные коды нужной им версии Linux-а](https://www.kernel.org/), вносят в них какие-то свои исправления (патчи), задают параметры сборки для включения нужных и исключения ненужных возможностей и компилируют ядро. Иными словами, дистрибутивы отличаются не только репозиториями и прикладными программами, но и вариациями ядра.

> ... и при этом можно установить именно это самое чистое ядро, а не какой-то из дистрибутивов?

Можно. Но так как ядро распространяется в исходных кодах, вам придётся скомпилировать из них свой вариант, заточенный конкретно под ваш компьютер и, возможно, потребности — штатный конфигуратор `make menuconfig` богат на опции:

[image: menuconfig]

*<sup>Главное окно графического конфигуратора параметров сборки Linux. Источник: [Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Linux_x86_3.10.0-rc2_Kernel_Configuration.png)</sup>*

Однако, получение даже минимальной рабочей системы — довольно длительный и многоэтапный процесс, требующий достаточных познаний в принципах работы Linux-а.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что само по себе ядро это уже по сути ОС, только без графического интерфейса (что-то вроде DOS) а сам GUI-интерфейс можно уже установить отдельно?

И снова не совсем. Ядро — это всего лишь прослойка между программами и железом. В случае Linux-а там в комплекте ещё идут драйвера.

Чтобы получить что-то, похожее на DOS, вам дополнительно потребуются как минимум [GNU Coreutils](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Coreutils) — набор программ, определяющих пользовательское окружение (`ls`, `cat`, `su` и т. д.), и загрузчик (например, `grub`, `lilo`), который будет загружать ядро при включении компьютера.

Кстати, именно из-за симбиоза ядра Linux и пакета программ GNU Coreutils операционную систему и называют GNU/Linux.

> Слышал много раз о том, что ядро в начале обычно нужно скомпилировать, а затем установить. Есть ли возможность получить уже скомпилированное ядро, распространяется ли оно в таком виде?

Распространение в исходных кодах — это своего рода политика разработчиков ядра, а потому скомпилированное ядро можно только выдрать из какого-то имеющегося дистрибутива.

> Хорошая ли идея - пытаться скомпилировать это самое ядро Linux на Windows, и насколько это вообще возможно?

Для сборки Linux вам потребуются компилятор GCC и компоновщик LD. *Теоретически*, [при сборке под Cygwin проблем быть не должно](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-06/msg00221.html) (если именно компилировать ядро), [но есть информация о трудностях с регистрозависимыми имёнами файлов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573786/2553424), которые Windows считает одинаковыми.

> Слышал много раз о всяких менеджерах пакетов, при помощи которых осуществляется установка различного софта в системах на базе Linux, при этом у каждой такой ОС (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint и т.д) свои собственные менеджеры пакетов. А как быть с чистым ядром? Каким образом на него что-то ставится?

Компиляцией из исходников. То есть в случае чистого ядра у вас под рукой всегда должен быть компилятор.

> Каким вообще образом распространяется софт для Linux? Только в open source, с последующей компиляцией? А такие штуки как установочные файлы, .exe-шники и прочее - обычно не используется?

Сборка из исходников является обязательной только для компонентов ядра, таких как драйвера. Прикладные же программы можно ставить и в виде двоичных файлов. Идёте на сайт разработчика, скачиваете какой-нибудь пакет. Затем, зная что любой пакет — это всего лишь архив одного из распространённых форматов, распаковываете его и раскидываете содержащиеся внутри файлы на подобающие им места в системе. И наконец удостоверяетесь, что у вас есть все библиотеки, нужные для запуска этой программы.

> Если есть только один ПК без установленной ОС, как обычно на него устанавливается ядро Linux?

Для сборки Linux нужна другая копия Linux. Поэтому вам надо хотя бы раздобыть live cd какого-нибудь дистрибутива.

Answer (score 7):

#### вводные сведения

> что такое Linux и с чем его едят.

*linux* — это программа (библиотека, если угодно), выполняющая функции ядра в ряде операционных систем.

наиболее известные операционные системы, использующие эту программу:

- *gnu/linux*
- *android* (фактически: *[dalvik](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik)/linux*, с недавних пор — *[art](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)/linux*)

операционная система *gnu* способна использовать и другие программы в качестве ядра. наиболее известны:

- [*gnu/kfreebsd*](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/)
- [*gnu/hurd*](https://www.debian.org/ports/hurd/)

дистрибутив — это операционная система плюс набор пользовательских программ и библиотек.

#### ответы на некоторые из вопросов

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что есть одно единственное и неповторимое ядро Linux, на базе которого разработаны все эти многочисленные дистрибутивы?

как понятно из вводных сведений, далеко не все дистрибутивы, которые в просторечии принято называть «linux-дистрибутивами», построены на основе того варианта операционной системы *gnu*, который используюет программу *linux* в качестве ядра.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что само по себе ядро это уже по сути ОС, только без графического интерфейса (что-то вроде DOS) а сам GUI-интерфейс можно уже установить отдельно?

нет, сама по себе программа *linux* для пользователя абсолютно бесполезна: во-первых, она не умеет загружать себя: требуется дополнительная программа-загрузчик (наиболее известные: *gnu/grub*, *lilo*, *syslinux*), во-вторых, даже будучи загруженной в память и запущенной, всё, что она может сделать, это выдать на экран надпись: «kernel panic. no init found» (шутка, в которой присутствует лишь доля шутки).

> Слышал много раз о том, что ядро в начале обычно нужно скомпилировать, а затем установить.

абсолютно подавляющее большинство пользователей дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu* этого не делают, а просто пользуются уже собранными для дистрибутива программами.

> Слышал много раз о всяких менеджерах пакетов, при помощи которых осуществляется установка различного софта в системах на базе Linux, при этом у каждой такой ОС (Ubuntu, Debian, Mint и т.д) свои собственные менеджеры пакетов.

все три перечисленных вами дистрибутива (ни разу не операционные системы, прошу заметить) используют один и тот же менеждер пакетов — [apt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool).

гораздо более существенным является не пакетный менеджер, а тот факт, что разными дистрибутивами (и разными версиями одного и того же дистрибутива) используются разные репозитории, т.е. разные *сборки* программ/библиотек.

> Если есть только один ПК без установленной ОС, как обычно на него устанавливается ядро Linux?

саму программу *linux* «ставить» не имеет ни малейшего смысла. нужен ещё как минимум загрузчик и собственно операционная система. а как максимум нужны и пользовательские программы/библиотеки (чтобы можно было сделать хоть что-то полезное).

для энтузиастов, желающих собрать себе систему «по кирпичику», есть весьма известное пособие: [linux from scrtatch](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_From_Scratch).

Answer (score 5):

Да, есть одно единственное и неповторимое ядро линукс. Но это не значит, что в него не могут вносить изменения другие, поэтому дистрибутивы могут иметь различия. Исходный код можно достать с гитхаба: https://github.com/torvalds/linux и так же там есть всякие мануалы.

Чистое ядро можно установить, но вы получите базовый набор (что-то вроде DOS) и все остальное придется собирать из исходных кодов, если таковые найдутся. Если охото этим позаниматься, то можете обратиться к [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Main_Page) и попробовать собрать его, у них как раз есть многостраничные Gentoo Handbook ([вот одна к примеру](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Alpha)) как это сделать.

Можно ли собрать Gentoo под Windows? Скорее всего можно, обеспечив компилятор всем необходимым, но это тот еще квест. В общем-то никто не мешает воспользоваться виртуальной машиной.

Менеждеры пакетов обращаются к FTP в интернете и скачивают оттуда уже заранее скомпилированный исходный код в пакете. При этом в самом Linux предусмотрена возможность этот список пополнять и изменять. Хотя из-за определенных отличий в системе не все их них могут корректно встать под другую систему, даже в пределах разных версий одного дистрибутива. Ну на чистом думаю понятно - компилировать вручную.

На пятый вопрос опять же есть Handbook от Gentoo из которого можно подчерпнуть эти знания.

P.S. Как правило никто не изучает Linux с ядра, если вы не разработчик ОС, а изучение проходит через изучение терминала, bash, заведение пользователей, изучение каталогов, встроенных инструментов, попытки настройки сети, поднятие сервера с простеньким сайтом и прочее администрирование. А если вы разработчик ОС, то опять же этим никто не занимается с самого начала, так как есть книги Тоненбаума (одна из которых о Minix и вдохновила Линуса написать свою ОС).

Answer (score 3):

Всё сказанное ранее - правильно, хотелось бы добавить по мелочам:

1. Если вы желаете ПОЗНАКОМИТЬСЯ с linux, то разбираться со сборкой и установкой ядра - самый безумный вариант. Просто возьмите любой live образ любого дистрибутива Linux (на CD или на флэшке - их полно в иНете) - посмотрите, понажимайте кнопочки.
2. Если заинтересовало - установите этот дистрибутив на свой комп. Как правило, при загрузке всех Live образов выскакивает меню, в котором есть пункт "Установить". Просто выберите этот пункт и произойдёт вполне аккуратная установка этого дистрибутива на Ваш комп. Если на компе присутствовал виндовоз, то ничего с ним не случится. Установщик спросит Вас, сколько пространства на HD Вы выделеяете под Linux. Он настроит загрузчик с меню выбора ОС и установит самые ходовые приложения. Вы получите ГОТОВУЮ к работе систему.
3. Очень важный момент, который принципиально отличает Linux от Windows - наличие репозитариев. Вам не надо буде шариться по инету, искать, где лежит интересующая Вас программа, разбираться с процессом установки, проверять наличие требуемых библиотек, проверять наличие обновлений и прочее... Всё это сделает за Вас системный установщик. В реальности, существует только два типа установщиков - для пакетов DEB и пакетов RPM. Что Вы выберете при установки (тип дистрибутива) с тем и будете иметь дело в дальнейшем. Поверьте - это огромное преимущество, по сравнению с виндой!

Comment: У винды тоже есть подобия репозиториев. Например [choco](https://chocolatey.org/)