# Линукс дистрибутив с минимальным набором утилит для запуска java команд

Tags: linux, distribution

Подскажите линукс дистрибутив (или что удалить лишнего), чтобы было возможно запускать только java команды? Мне не нужен ни GUI, ни apt-get, ничего такого.

Как я понял, нужно оставить лишь папку bin, в которой сидит bash и его друзья. я прав?

Comment: `Docker` пробовали?

Comment: А как вы без apt-get собираетесь ставить jvm и её зависимости?

Comment: как минимум еще нужны /lib (/usr/lib) потому ничего из /bin не заработает без библиотек.так же наверняка понадобиться /etc, /var, /dev. /tmp иначе в систему не войдете

Comment: А так, самый минимальный дистрибутив — это отсутствие дистрибутива, [то есть сам Linux с минимальной обвязкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841073/208074). Вот только развёртывание системы до необходимого вам состояния займёт пару дней, а то и более.

Comment: @Arhad, jdk будет уже вшит.

Comment: @Mike, разве? Я вот удалил `/lib` и `var`. команды `java -version` работают. Правда компилировать еще не пробовал

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Соберите свой, если есть часов 40-60 свободного времени. Linux From Scratch например дает пошаговые инструкцию.

На сайте Oracle есть исходники, можете скрафтить сами.

Минимальные дистры:

- http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/
- https://www.archlinux.org/
- http://puppylinux.com/

Исходники OpenJDK

- http://openjdk.java.net/

Я обычно ставлю тарбол от Oracle, там все в одном архиве - целевой дистр Ubuntu 16.04: гоняется 2 кастомных приложения, сами приложения больше, чем весь дистр.